# Pollard's p - 1 factorization algo is described in most books as finding a B-smooth p-1, while it's actually trying to find B-powersmooth p - 1. Why?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

In Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm for factoring $N$, you try to find a $L$ such that $p - 1$ divides $L$.

You do this by trying to find a B-Powersmooth $p - 1$ by trying either $n$ = $1$ to $B$, and calculating $n!$ for each & checking $gcd(a^{n!} - 1, N)$. (The exponentiation is done mod N - omitting it for simplicity)
Another method instead of using factorial is to use the LCM of the range instead of the factorial.

In each of these, IMHO, you are trying to find a B-Powersmooth $p - 1$. Many books describe it so, but I have also seen a lot of books which describe it as trying to find a B-smooth $p - 1$.

B-smooth & B-powersmooth have different meanings, so why is used interchangeably?

Examples of books which use B-smooth instead of B-powersmooth - Joy of Factoring by Wagstaff, Mathematical Cryptography by Silverman. The Wikipedia article on Pollard's $p - 1$, ans Nigel Smart's book refer to it as B-powersmooth.

So why this confusion?

Comment: The prime powers can be captured with a slight modification or if we use the factorial (which however slows down the process dramatically). A good workaround is to take all numbers upto some limit and above this limit, only primes are used. This way the risk to miss a factor that would have been found by taking all numbers can be made quite small.

Comment: Although some large factors have been found using this method, the power of the p-1-method is quite limited. Usually, only factors upto about $15$ digits are found within a reasonable time. ECM is a huge improvement.